# Bootstrap alert dialog is not displayed further after auto-close

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap alert to display application messages. I use $timeout function to close the alerts automatically.

```
$scope.alerts.push({header: header, msg: message, type: type});
            $timeout(function() {
                $scope.alerts.splice(0, 1);
            }, 3000);
```

For the first time the bootstrap alert is displayed and it autocloses in 3 seconds. After that  it does not show error/info messages for any action done in the application. Is there anything I need to add.? I am new to angular js. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Bootstrap alert is removed from the DOM when you click on **Close**, you need to use `close.bs.alert` event if you want the alert to stay in the DOM and be reused.

```
<div class="alert alert-warning collapse" id="my-alert">
        <a href="#" data-dismiss="alert" class="close">&times;</a>
        <p>My alert.</p>
</div>

var alert = $("#my-alert");    
alert.on("close.bs.alert", function () {
    alert.hide(); //hide the alert
    return false; //don't remove it from DOM
});
```

Find out more at [#alerts-usage](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#alerts-usage).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are polling the `$timeout`. Hope this will help you

In HTML

```
<alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts" type="{{alert.type}}" close="closeAlert($index)">{{alert.msg}}</alert>
  <button class='btn btn-default' ng-click="addAlert()">Add Alert</button>
```

In Controller

```
$scope.alerts = [];

  $scope.addAlert = function() {
    $scope.alerts.push({msg: 'Another alert!'});
    $scope.autoHide();
  };
  $scope.autoHide =function(){
                  $timeout(function() {
                        $scope.alerts.splice(0, 1);
                  }, 3000);
  }

  $scope.closeAlert = function(index) {
    $scope.alerts.splice(index, 1);
  };
```

Comment: <alert ng-repeat="alert in alerts"
   type="alert.type" close="closeAlert($index)">
  <strong>{{alert.header}}</strong>
  <br />
  {{alert.msg}}</alert>
  </div>
This is the view. I tried to add the autohide() in controller. still the issue remains

Comment: Can you be able to give a fiddle or plunker of your code.